# Deployment of statically linked Qt application backward compatibility

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gcc

This is my first attempt at making a Qt Application work on different systems.

I have opted for static linking method.I have already compiled the sources of Qt 5.5 and compiled my application with the static Qt. The executable is working fine on my computer. 
My operating system is Ubuntu 15.04. But when I tried to run the same executable on Ubuntu 14.04 then I ran into trouble. The key details of the error message are given below.

> libstdc++.so.6  cxxabi_1.3.8 not found

I did a standard Google search and realised it was because I had a newer version of it on my machine, the machine where I had created the executable. There were so many different approaches to handle this problem. One of the solutions I saw involved shipping your own copy of `libstdc++.so` with the executable. But when I tried to copy the .so file to a pen drive, there was a warning saying that the file system does not support such files.

My question is , what am I doing wrong ? Also if I wanted to make the executable target Ubuntu 10.04, what would be the correct procedure handling the backward compatibility issues. I know that one method would be to install the same OS on my machine and then create the executable , is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libstd++ is backward compatible but not forward compatible, which means you can run a program with a newer version of libstdc++ than the one you compiled it with but not vice-versa. This is what you experienced.

One way to deal with this issue is using older OS versions as the build machine. When you for example use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, you'll get [this list of compatible target systems](https://www.kullo.net/en/supported-linux-distributions/).

The build system you're using will probably limit available compilers. On Ubuntu 14.04 you get GCC 4.8, which is good for most C++11 and packages for clang 3.6 are available, which will give you full C++14 support.

Targeting Ubuntu 10.04 will be challenging if you do not want to use a stone age compiler.

The idea of shipping libstdc++ will not help you much because you'll run into the same problem with libc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but is there any standard old OS  which companies making qt applications  use for building to target the old Ubuntu versions , that was my major doubt

Comment: What compatibility do you need? What compiler do you need? Which C++ standard do you use in your application? This is a very custom question. Given that all typical Linux distribution are made to compile their packages from source code there is no general answer to this question. Linux is not optimized for proprietary software.

Comment: I would like compatibility from ubuntu 10.04 onwards, c++ standard gnu++98, sorry for not being specific, but I earlier thought there would be a general way of going about it.

Comment: Looks like you can use Ubuntu 10.04 with the bundled GCC 4.4 to compile Qt and your application since *Qt can be compiled with any compiler supporting C++98 standard. So GCC 4.3 should do it just fine* http://forum.qt.io/topic/39674/minimal-gcc-version-for-5-3-and-gcc-used-with-distributed-libraries/2 This might work until Qt 5.6. Starting with Qt 5.7, Qt requires a C++11 compiler.